# Append item to MongoDB document array in PyMongo without re-insertion

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am using MongoDB as the back-end database for Python web application (PyMongo + Bottle). Users can upload files and optionally 'tag' these files during upload. The tags are stored as a list within the document, per below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561c199e038e42b10956e3fc"),
    "tags" : [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ],
    "ref" : "4780"
}
```

I am trying to allow users to append new tags to any document. I came up with something like this:

```
def update_tags(ref, new_tag)
    # fetch desired document by ref key as dict
    document = dict(coll.find_one({'ref': ref}))
    # append new tag
    document['tags'].append(new_tag)
    # re-insert the document back into mongo
    coll.update(document)
```

(fyi; `ref` key is always unique. this could easily be `_id` as well.)
It seems like there should be a way to just update the 'tags' value directly without pulling back the entire document and re-inserting. Am I missing something here?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You don't need to use to retrieve the document first just use the `.update` method with the [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator.

```
def update_tags(ref, new_tag):
    coll.update({'ref': ref}, {'$push': {'tags': new_tag}})
```

Since update is deprecated you should use the [`find_one_and_update`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.9/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update) or the [`update_one`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.9/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) method if you are using pymongo 2.9 or newer

Comment: What is the difference between the two? Just the return value (the document vs an UpdateResult object) ? When do you use one or the other?

Comment: What happens if 'tags' field doesn't exist?

Comment: If `tags` field doesn't exist, it is created. @GauravOjha

Comment: Will it delete the old record?

Comment: must be an array but is of type object in document this error pops up

Comment: what happens if the new_tag already exits?

Comment: When I try appending a dictionary to a list, I get `{TypeError}unhashable type: 'dict'`. Why is PyMongo trying to hash the dictionary, and how do I append a dictionary to the list?

Answer (score 11):

You can simply do

1) If you want to append single entry

```
def update_tags(ref, new_tag):
    coll.update({'ref': ref}, {'$push': {'tags': new_tag}})
```

eg:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561c199e038e42b10956e3fc"),
    "tags" : [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ],
    "ref" : "4780"
}
>> update_tags("4780", "tag4")
{'updatedExisting': True, u'nModified': 1, u'ok': 1, u'n': 1}
>> coll.find_one({"ref":"4780"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561c199e038e42b10956e3fc"),
    "tags" : [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" , "tag4" ],
    "ref" : "4780"
}
```

2) If you want to append multiple entries

```
def update_tags(ref, new_tag):
    coll.update({'ref': ref}, {'$pushAll': {'tags': new_tag}}) #type of new_tag is list
```

eg:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561c199e038e42b10956e3fc"),
    "tags" : [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" ],
    "ref" : "4780"
}
>> update_tags("4780", ["tag5", "tag6", "tag7"])
{'updatedExisting': True, u'nModified': 1, u'ok': 1, u'n': 1}
>> coll.find_one({"ref":"4780"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561c199e038e42b10956e3fc"),
    "tags" : [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3" , "tag4" , "tag5", "tag6", "tag7" ],
    "ref" : "4780"
}
```

Note: If the key is not already present, then mongo will create new key.

Comment: pymongo.errors.WriteError: Unknown modifier: $pushAll

Comment: `$pushAll` won't work for appending multiple values to an array. Use `$push` with the `$each` modifier to append multiple values to the array field.
`{'$push': {'tags': { '$each': new_tags_array}}}`

Answer (score 9):

Just to add to @ssytvane answer,and to answer @Guarav: you can add "upsert = True" if it does not exist:

```
def update_tags(ref, new_tag):
    coll.update({'ref': ref}, {'$push': {'tags': new_tag}}, upsert = True)
```

or

```
def update_tags(ref, new_tag):
    coll.update_one({'ref': ref}, {'$push': {'tags': new_tag}}, upsert = True)
```

Comment: what is ref here?

Comment: upsert (optional): When True, inserts a new document if no document matches the query. Defaults to False. https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.9/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one

Answer (score 5):

There had been some good answers that are correct but in my opinion writing update_tags this way is better and more usable:

```
def update_tags(ref, *args):
    coll.update_one(ref, {'$push': {'tags': {'$each': args}}})
```

this way you can do both appending one tag or appending many tags:

```
>> update_tags(ref, 'tag5')
```

```
>> update_tags(ref, 'tag5', 'tag6')
```

```
>> list_of_new_tags = do_something_that_returns_list_of_tags()
>> update_tags(ref, *list_of_new_tags)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$push`

```
collection_name.update_one({'ref': ref}, {'$push': {'tags': new_tag}})
```

You can update multiple arrays in a single query

```
collection_name.update_one({'ref': ref}, {'$push': {'field1': value1, 'filed2': value2}})
```

Values can be pushed to push like below.

```
{ $push: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }
```