# How to insert a dictionary to a list in mongodb?

Tags: python, mongodb

I need to insert a dictionary to a list in a list in mongodb,

I have this db:

```
{library_id:1, library_name:rj, library_books:[{book_name:r&d, page_num:312, book_tags:[]}, {book_name:java, page_num:122, book_tags:[]}]}
```

and I want to insert into book_tags according to fitting book_name

so it will be like this (for book_name r&d)-

```
{library_id:1, library_name:rj, library_books:[{book_name:r&d, page_num:312, book_tags:[{tag_name:study, tag_description:self learning}]},{book_name:java, page_num:122, book_tags:[]}]}
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you already written some code?

Comment: You need to begin with some library. Pymongo or motor (motor_asyncio for Python3 and motor_tornado for Python2).

Comment: hey, yes I am using pymongo,
it is a part of several functions that needs to insert the details to the db (so I can't insert that in the begining..) 
one of them should insert book_tags as I have described..

Answer (score 0):

You should to update the field. This seems like this:

```
db.mongodb.update_one(
       { 'library_books.book_name': your_book_name },
       { $push: { 'library_books.book_name': your_tags } }
    )
```

Maybe you need to use `$each` instead of `$push`. The difference is describing [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189258/append-item-to-mongodb-document-array-in-pymongo-without-re-insertion) answer too. I think this is your way.