# Append item to Mongo Array

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb document I am trying to update. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189258/append-item-to-mongodb-document-array-in-pymongo-without-re-insertion) was helpful, but every time I insert into the database, the data is inserted as an array inside of the array whereas I just want to insert the object directly into the array.

Here is what I am doing.

```
# My function to update the array
def append_site(gml_id, new_site):
    col.update_one({'gml_id': gml_id}, {'$push': {'websites': new_site}}, upsert = True)
```

```
# My Dataframe
data = {'name':['ABC'], 
        'gml_id':['f9395e09'],
        'url':['ABC.com']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
# Grouping data for upsert
df = df.groupby(['gml_id']).apply(lambda x: x[['name','url']].to_dict('r')).reset_index().rename(columns={0:'websites'})
```

```
# Apply function to every row
df.apply(lambda row: append_site(row['gml_id'], row['websites']), axis = 1)
```

Here is the outcome:

```
{
    "gml_id": "f9395e09",
    "websites": [
        {
            "name": "XYZ.com",
            "url": "...xyz.com"
        },
        [
            {
                "name": "ABC.com",
                "url": "...abc.com"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Here is the goal:

```
{
    "gml_id": "f9395e09",
    "websites": [
        {
            "name": "XYZ.com",
            "url": "...xyz.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "ABC.com",
            "url": "...abc.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the `websites` array is being appended with a `list` object rather than a `dict`, i.e. `new_site` is a `list`.

As you haven't posted where you call `append_site()`, this is a litle speculative, but you could try changing this line and seeing if it gives the effect you need.

```
col.update_one({'gml_id': gml_id}, {'$push': {'websites': new_site[0]}}, upsert = True)
```

Alternatively make sure you are passing a `dict` object to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing an unncessary groupby, I decided to leave the dataframe flat and then adjust the function like this:

```
def append_site(gml_id, name, url):
    col.update_one({'gml_id': gml_id}, {'$push': {'websites': {'name': name, 'url': url}}}, upsert = True)
```

I now call it like this: `df.apply(lambda row: append_site(row['gml_id'], row['url'], row['name']), axis = 1)`

Works perfectly fine.