# Is there any way to push a dictionary/object to a list in a mongo db collection using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

rs_objects is a list of dict type objects [{}, ... , {}]

```
def push_update(
    key_identifier,
    identifier_value,
    array_key,
    rs_objects):

    # stuff to establish conn and select a db and collection

    res = collection.find_one_and_update(            
        {
            str(key_identifier): {
                "$eq": str(identifier_value)
            }
        },
        {
            '$push': {
                str(array_key): {
                    "$each": rs_objects
                }
            }
        },
        return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER
    )
    return res
```

That's the way I've been trying to, but responses are still None Type and the documents remain unchanged in the database

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189258/append-item-to-mongodb-document-array-in-pymongo-without-re-insertion

Comment: I've already tried these as I showed in the code extract but I don't really know if $push operator in pymongo has support for dictionary insertions.

Comment: the code you posted is working for me. can you show where it is not working

Comment: I call the function from a celery job (but that must not represent any problem).
The way I call the function is something like this:

```rs_object = [{  "field_a":"value_a", "field_b":"value_b", "field_c":"value_c",},  ...]

# Set the new rs array
result =push_update(conn,"my_db","any_collection","key_constraint","value_to_match" "array_field_name", rs_object)
```

Here, result ends with a None Type value

Comment: try printing `res` in `push_update()` function. If it prints`None` then it doesn't find the matching document.