# PyMongo insert an object into an already existing array in a Document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi

I want to insert a new object into an array in mongodb everytime a post api request takes place. I am using python and pymongo along with fastapi. Consider this as an example:

```py
id1: ObjectId(...)
id2: ObjectId(...)
messages: []
```

what I want to do is... Everytime an api request takes place a message be added to the messages array. Like this:

```py
id1: ObjectId(...)
id2: ObjectId(...)
messages: [
  "Hello"
]
```

What would be the correct way to do so with pymongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the `update` method with the `$push` operator.

Maybe the answers for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189258/append-item-to-mongodb-document-array-in-pymongo-without-re-insertion) will help you.